# How to display elements from the map? (React)

Tags: reactjs

I want to make the list appear in textarea as a list, just as I did not find the answer how to replace the data in textarea, I also have problems in the process of updating the changed information  (I don’t quite understand how it happens) please help with my problem, I am new and only write a week

I tried to change the map to an array but the result did not bring it and I finally got confused...

```js
class SettingsPage extends React.Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      blackList : this.props.settings.blackList
    }
  }

_handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      blackList : event.target.value
    })
  };

_handleClick = (event) => {
    this.props.dispatch(settingsActions.updateSettings(event))
  }



render () {
    const { classes } = this.props
    const listItems = this.state.blackList.map((number) =>
      <li>{number}</li>
    );

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Typography variant="h4" gutterBottom>
          Settings
        </Typography>
        <Divider className={ classes.divider }/>
        <form>
          <p><b> Brands: </b></p>
            <textarea className="form-control" rows="10" ref="summaryContent" onChange={this._handleChange}>
              <ul>{listItems}</ul>
              </textarea>
            <Button size="small" color="primary" onClick={this._handleClick}>
              Add
            </Button>
          <ul>{listItems}</ul>
        </form>
        <Button size="small" color="primary" onClick= {this._toProfile}>
          To profile
        </Button>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

in textrea shows objects arrays [object object],[object object] and I don't quite understand why? How to get the value from the map if the key is null there

Comment: is `number` from `this.state.blackList.map((number)` an object or is it a primitive value (number/string/boolean)? If it's an object you can display it `<li>{JSON.stringify(number)}</li>`. That being said, you should probably instead render the properties you specifically need: `<li>{number.someProperty} {number.someOtherProperty}</li>`. Also are you trying to render text or HTML in the textarea https://jsfiddle.net/kzvo439e/?

Comment: blackList this is an array, it contains 8 names that I want to get, but it does not go into the textarea

Comment: In the code your shared, you are putting `{listItems}` which is mapped from `blackList` into `textarea`. Can you please share what an item in `blackList` looks like?

Comment: export const settings = { blackList: [
      'OEM',
      'Genuine',
      'Original Replacement',
      'authentic',
      'Samsung',
      'Apple',
      'Disney',
      'Sony',
    ],}  This is how it looks, you are sorry for English, sometimes the translator does not translate well)